# boost and cpp-netlib make compile ERROR

Tags: c++, boost, makefile

[SOLVED] created symlinks from /usr/lib/lib/* to /usr/lib*

[UPDATE 3] **NEW VERSION:**

Ok, I think I fixed something

use  `find / -name "libboost_system.*"`
outout was

```
/usr/include/boost/lib/libboost_system.so
/usr/include/boost/lib/libboost_system.a
/usr/include/boost/lib/libboost_system.so.1.46.1
/usr/lib/lib/libboost_system.so
/usr/lib/lib/libboost_system.a
/usr/lib/lib/libboost_system.so.1.46.1
/usr/local/include/boost_1_46_1/bin.v2/libs/system/build/gcc-4.4.3/release/link-static/threading-multi/libboost_system.a
/usr/local/include/boost_1_46_1/bin.v2/libs/system/build/gcc-4.4.3/release/threading-multi/libboost_system.so.1.46.1
/usr/local/lib/libboost_system.so
/usr/local/lib/libboost_system.a
/usr/local/lib/libboost_system.so.1.46.1
/root/tmp/boost_1_46_1/bin.v2/libs/system/build/gcc-4.4.3/release/link-static/threading-multi/libboost_system.a
/root/tmp/boost_1_46_1/bin.v2/libs/system/build/gcc-4.4.3/release/threading-multi/libboost_system.so.1.46.1
```

why are these files in `/usr/lib/lib` ? and is it a problem ?

and the     `ls -l /usr/lib/lib | grep boost_system`

```
ls -l /usr/lib/lib | grep boost_system
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   21574 2011-05-09 15:15 libboost_system.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      25 2011-05-09 15:15 libboost_system.so -> libboost_system.so.1.46.1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   20053 2011-05-09 15:15 libboost_system.so.1.46.1
```

atm my makefile looks like

```
LIBPATH=-I/usr/local/include/cpp-netlib 
LIBS=$(LIBPATH) -lboost_system  -lboost_filesystem -lboost_thread -lpthread 

LD=g++ -g 
CPP=g++ -c -g $(LIBS)

P=.
OBJ=$(P)/tmp/main.o $(P)/tmp/CLink.o $(P)/tmp/CFetcher.o

main:   $(OBJ); $(LD) $(OBJ) $(LIBS) -o $@


$(P)/tmp/CLink.o:   $(P)/src/CLink.cpp $(P)/include/CLink.h; $(CPP) -c $< -o $@
$(P)/tmp/CFetcher.o:    $(P)/src/CFetcher.cpp $(P)/include/CFetcher.h; $(CPP) -c $< -o $@
$(P)/tmp/main.o:    $(P)/src/main.cpp $(P)/include/CLink.h $(P)/include/CFetcher.h ; $(CPP) -c $< -o $@

all:
    touch $(P)/tmp/*.o;
    touch main;
    rm -f $(P)/tmp/*.o;
    rm -f main;
    make main;
```

The Compiler output is lie

```
g++ -c -g -I/usr/local/include/cpp-netlib  -lboost_system  -lboost_filesystem -lboost_thread -lpthread  -c src/main.cpp -o tmp/main.o
g++ -c -g -I/usr/local/include/cpp-netlib  -lboost_system  -lboost_filesystem -lboost_thread -lpthread  -c src/CLink.cpp -o tmp/CLink.o
g++ -c -g -I/usr/local/include/cpp-netlib  -lboost_system  -lboost_filesystem -lboost_thread -lpthread  -c src/CFetcher.cpp -o tmp/CFetcher.o
g++ -g  ./tmp/main.o ./tmp/CLink.o ./tmp/CFetcher.o -I/usr/local/include/cpp-netlib  -lboost_system  -lboost_filesystem -lboost_thread -lpthread  -o main
```

So for me all looks nice but when i try to run the program

./main

```
./main: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_system.so.1.46.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The `-l` flags must come *after* the source files on linker command-line.

   Yes, that means you'll have to split the `LD` definition to `LD` and `LIBS`, put all the `-L` and `-l` flags in the later and change the link command to:

   $(LD) $(OBJ) $(LIBS) -o $@
2. The library (`.so` (dynamic) or `.a` (static)) files have to be the same version as the headers. While there are boost 1.46.1 headers installed in `/usr/local/include/boost_1_46_1/`, the corresponding library files don't seem to be installed at all. The only installed libraries are version 1.40.0 in `/usr/lib`, so the linker finds those (`/usr/lib` would be searched by default even if you didn't include the `-L/usr/lib` flag), but they don't contain the symbols expected by 1.46.1.

   Note that when linking against shared library (using shared libraries is strongly recommended in Linux), the linker looks for the file with `.so` extension, but that is usually symlink to a file with added version suffix and the linker reads it and records the target name in the binary. That way programs compiled against the .1.40 will continue to work when 1.46 is installed, because the `libboost*.so.1.40.0` may (and have to) stay around after the `.so` is redirected to the 1.46.1 version.

   It should be even possible to install like:

   ```
   /usr/local/lib/boost_1_46_1/libboost_system-mt.so -> /usr/local/lib/libboost_system-mt.so.1.46
   /usr/local/lib/libboost_system-mt.so.1.46 -> /usr/local/lib/libboost_system-mt.so.1.46.1
   /usr/local/lib/libboost_system-mt.so.1.46.1
   ```

   and compile using `-L/usr/local/lib/boost_1_46_1`, though I currently can't find any package that would do it to confirm this. This way you could have development files for multiple versions installed and switch between them using explicit `-I` and `-L` flags while dynamic linker would still find the runtime files, for which it only looks in `/usr/local/lib`, `/usr/lib` and `/lib` (it can be configured in `/etc/ld.so.conf`, but that's the default).

Comment: another common name for `$(LIBS)` would be `$(LDFLAGS)`

Comment: hey thx for the answer, i hope i understand what you mean. just look to the main post. is it correct ? because the make failed... greetz

Comment: @Roby: It is what I meant. I believe you want *either* the -mt variants *or* the others, not both and you may need to change the order of the libraries.

Comment: @Roby: Are you sure you have headers and libraries from the same version of boost? You use the `-L` flags with paths where includes are, but the libraries are elsewhere (`/usr/local/lib/boost_1_46_1` maybe?), so libraries from `/usr/lib` are being used and if they are different version, it won't link.

Comment: @Roby: I think the `-L` flags are incorrect. They shouldn't be the same as the `-I` ones. Can you `find /lib /usr/lib /usr/local -name 'libboost_system-mt.*', please?

Comment: @Jan :-/ atm nothin is working more :P i think so, they are from the same version, but dont know how to check :-/

Comment: @Roby: I told you to try finding all `libboost_system-mt.*` files. Post the list. Than I can tell you which one it is using and whether it's the right one and explain why it does what it does.

Comment: @Roby: Indeed, you need to install matching headers and libraries (editing answer for correct form)

Comment: @Jan: i fixed the full post on the top of this page. i think i was generating new errors :D and fixed one ? :D

Comment: @Jan: omfg THX i fixed the problem useing symlinks from /usr/lib/lib to /usr/lib/ THX for youre help!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Execute your application with strace.  This will show the location were you app is looking for your boost libs. In my case an app was looking in  `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` for boost libs where the actual location was `/usr/lib/lib`. A simple export statement adding the paths for the boost shared libs in my case `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/lib` worked a treat.

output from strace

```
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.46.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
exit_group(127)                         = ?
```